# How to get cpu usage percentage in macos with Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cpu-usage

I'm trying to do an activity monitor for **MacOS** (I know that there is a mac app called activity monitor that tell that) so I want to get the cpu usage percentage with Swift. I found some similar questions but they only work with iOS. I also found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785069/) in Objective-C but not in Swift and I don't understand very well Objective-C (I'm a Swift person).

Comment: You could try to use this to get started https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744372/get-cpu-usage-ios-swift

Comment: @SamHollenbach Thank you but I'm trying to do it for mac, not iOS

Comment: Ah I see my mistake. I did find this resource that may be helpful though. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33857707/6685140

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get CPU percent usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785069/get-cpu-percent-usage)

Comment: @AdriánQB I added my Swift conversion to the other question, to have it all together: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53901721/1033581

Comment: @Cœur Thank you very much