# Swift: Limit CPU time of thread, queue or operation

Tags: swift, multithreading

I employ a native C library in my iOS app. Calling the code directly puts it on the main thread (of course depending on from where I call it) so I have created a new queue in order to leave the main thread for the call.

```
let cProcessingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "cProcessingQueue")


cProcessingQueue.async {
    //call that launches the c operation
}
```

This keeps the UI responsive. However, on larger data sets this has the potential to throw crashes that contain statements like the following:

```
Action taken:    Process killed
CPU:             48 seconds cpu time over 54 seconds (88% cpu average), exceeding limit of 80% cpu over 60 seconds
```

Is there  I can apply to have some kind of hard(ish) limit like "`qos: .background` will always limit the usage to 50%" in order to slow down the C lib execution in first place? I'm fine with using NSOperation or whatever there is but that would probably the most convenient solution.

A few other ideas I can think of are:

1. Feeding smaller chunks of data with some delay in between, however then we have arbitrary wait times that go unused
2. Watching the CPU time as shown in [Get CPU usage IOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744372/get-cpu-usage-ios-swift) and modifying the C library to support halting executions

but all in all, the "thread-related limit" would definitely the easiest solution out there.

Comment: Did lowering QoS of the queue change the situation somehow? `NSOperation` uses GCD under the hood anyway, so i'm kind of doubtful it can do anything beyond what you can achieve with setting QoS of your `cProcessingQueue`.

Comment: I _feel_ like leaving it empty (so if I understood it will set to `.default` which for some reason we shouldn't use explicitly) made the situation a bit better (had it on `.userInitiated` before) and there adre a few benchmarks that show how "worse" qos' perform slower however this kind of "hard limit" would still be my favorite

Comment: I'm not aware of any hard limit functionality available for `GCD`, `NSOperation` or `NSThread` classes (and apparently the classes were designed like that intentionally), however IMO setting low priority for execution, and letting the system decide how to work with it is exactly what you are asking for. Be advised, however, that setting `QoS` of the custom queue does not necessary mean it has base queue of lower `QoS`. You may want to set it explicitly like that: `DispatchQueue(label: "mQueue", qos: .background, autoreleaseFrequency: .never, target: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))`

Comment: ...and if it doesn't work, i believe the only option is to try to artificially slowdown execution of the C library, like you yourself proposed

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I really appreciate it!